# Android sqlite can't create TEMP table

Tags: android, sqlite, temporary

I'd like to create and use a temporary table in a android sqlite database.
SQL statement is executed without any exception but no table is created!
Running my app with the sample code below, I got no tables:

**START EDIT**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DB_NAME = "mydb.db";
private static DatabaseHelper instance;

public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context){
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    return instance;
}

private DatabaseHelper(Context c) {
    super(c,DB_NAME,null,1);
}

@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.enableWriteAheadLogging ();
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // lots of table creation
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE my_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT)");
    // more tables ....
}}
...... sample 
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(this);
```

**END EDIT**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("create TEMP table my_temp_table (id integer primary key, value text)"); // no exceptions

Cursor cursor = db.query("SQLITE_TEMP_MASTER", null, null, null, null, null, null);

while( cur.moveToNext()) {
    // no lines (no temporary tables)
}
```

If I create a temporary table from a select statement and then query (within the same db connection) the created table, I get "no such table .... exception"!

```
db.execSQL("create TEMP table my_temp_table as select * from my_table");
Cursor cursor = db.query("temp.my_temp_table", null, null, null, null, null, null);
^^^ no such table: temp.my_temp_table(code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM temp.my_temp_table
```

What is confusing me is that ... the same sql code works perfectly within SQLiteStudio i.e. outside the app and outside the android device.
Maybe I forgot to enable something or ... I need specific device permission?

Comment: Can you provide the code from your databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase() please?

Comment: Sure! I updated my post with DatabaseHelper class

Comment: Are you aware of this? http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#tempdb  Are you sure, you didn't close the connection which created TEMP table?

Comment: Yes, I am.  As you can see in my code, I get a db connection (writeable) and with the same connection I create temp table and query that table .... Did I misunderstand something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable Write-Ahead Logging with `db.enableWriteAheadLogging()`, SQLiteDatabase automatically multiplexes database connections. The connection used for `db.query(...)` is not the same one used for `db.execSQL("CREATE TEMP TABLE ...")`.

You can wrap `db.query(...)` in a transaction and enforce SQLiteDatabase to use the same connection as `execSQL`.

```
db.beginTransaction();
Cursor cursor = db.query("temp.my_temp_table", null, null, null, null, null, null);
try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // ...
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `create temp table x` is a table `x` not `temp.x`

Change your code to use `my_temp_table`

Comment: I changed my code as suggested and , again,  "no such table .... exception" is thrown!